# Unable to display Certain PDF fonts in iPad

Tags: ipad, pdf, ios4

I am rendering PDF's in my ebook reader app(iPad). Everything works fine in iOS 4.2.1. But the problem arises when i run the same code in iOS 4.3.3. The font which is being displayed perfectly in 4.2.2 is not getting displayed properly in 4.3.3. Some fonts are being displayed with dark background colors and square boxes while some others are not at all being displayed.
I sense it has got something to do with the iOS version. Is it a bug from Apple side or should i do something to rectify this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PDFs can have the fonts embedded so that if the target system doesn't know the font it doesn't try any strange substitutions.  What is the source of your PDFs?  Are you able to check/change whether all fonts are embedded?

Comment: +1 .thanks for the reply jowie.... i dont know the source of the PFD's as they are given by my clients. i dont know the process of checking the fints in PDF.. can you tell me the process of doing it.

Comment: Hello A for Alpha.  Depending on your viewer, you should be able to get the properties for the PDF.  This should list fonts used, and hopefully whether they are embedded.  I have seen a lot of discussion about alternate viewers for PDF because of problems with the built-in viewer so if it is an option for you, perhaps try using a different viewer library.  One of my colleagues did this because of memory issues - built into the application and thus transparent to the user of the app.

Answer (score 1):

For me the only thing that worked was (on a mac, sorry) open the existing pdf with "Preview" and make a "Save As", I think as preview can generate pdf files, it re-embed the fonts accordingly for apple, so iPad too.